# How to create Date on server(there utc timezone) and correct display on client?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, nestjs, date-fns

We escape of using moment now and use date-fns instead. In some places we still use moment on front.
Example of code on server

```
//date in yyyy/mm/dd format in query params
startOfDay = StartOfDay(new Date(date));
return startOfDay
```

And when I display this date on front, she changes to local timezone(-4 hours). If i use date-fns-tz and convert to Canada timezone, I will get date with -4 hours and after display -4 hours more. How to resole this issue? I need to add 4 hours to date for my current timeZone. My utcOffset = 4.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure what function your are currently using from date-fns-ts, what has worked for me is to use utcToZonedTime(). This function gets

> [a date/time in the local time of any time zone from UTC time](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz#utctozonedtime)

```
import { utcToZonedTime } from 'date-fns-tz'

const now = new Date() // UTC
const nowCustomTimeZone = utcToZonedTime(now, 'Europe/Amsterdam')
```

Comment: When I set 'Canada/Tronto' timeZone, date will be on server -4 hours and on client -4 more hours = 4pm prev day

Comment: What's the input date's timezone?

Comment: The input date's timezone is utc